# Using C++ & cURL, How to get Image by url that needed user id & password

Tags: c++, curl

Hi I'm trying to get image by url using c++ and cURL.

I found this code and it works. however an image of url that requires an ID & password, didn't work this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t callbackfunction(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata)
{
FILE* stream = (FILE*)userdata;
if (!stream)
{
    printf("!!! No stream\n");
    return 0;
}

size_t written = fwrite((FILE*)ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

bool download_jpeg(char* url)
{
FILE* fp = fopen("out.jpg", "wb");
if (!fp)
{
    printf("!!! Failed to create file on the disk\n");
    return false;
}

CURL* curlCtx = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curlCtx, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curlCtx, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
curl_easy_setopt(curlCtx, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callbackfunction);
curl_easy_setopt(curlCtx, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

CURLcode rc = curl_easy_perform(curlCtx);
if (rc)
{
    printf("!!! Failed to download: %s\n", url);
    return false;
}

long res_code = 0;
curl_easy_getinfo(curlCtx, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &res_code);
if (!((res_code == 200 || res_code == 201) && rc != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK))
{
    printf("!!! Response code: %d\n", res_code);
    return false;
}

curl_easy_cleanup(curlCtx);

fclose(fp);

return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if (argc < 2)
{
   printf("Usage: %s <url>\n", argv[0]);
   return -1;
}

if (!download_jpeg(argv[1]))
{
    printf("!! Failed to download file: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return -1;
}

return 0;
}
```

what do I add something? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl's `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option for accessing built-in functionality for **HTTP authentication**, also `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` for setting **authentication type**.

**Example**:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
```

[Source](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/anyauthput.html)

[HTTPAUTH documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.html)

[USERPWD documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html)